TailwindCSS min width is not being applied
I am trying to use min-w-10 on an element, but it does not get applied as a style.
<span class="min-w-20 bg-red-500 inline-block">
    test
</span>

For example, the only style applied is .bg-red-500 and .inline-block. .min-w-20 is not being applied and I cannot see it in inspect element.
But using w-20 works and does apply.
<span class="w-20 bg-red-500 inline-block">
    test
</span>

In the above I can see .w-20, .inline-block and .bg-red-500 in inspect element.
However, if I define it manually, min-w-[200px] for example, it works. None of the min-w- classes work at all, unless I manually define the width in pixels.
It is not being superseded by anything, the element styles are not being applied at all, and nothing is being purged in the Tailwind CSS config file either. I have no other issues with classes not being applied, just with min-w-.

What version of Tailwind are you using?

Need more info here. What do you mean "is not rendered to the view"? Is the class on the element? Does the browser inspector show that class being applied? Can you recreate the issue on a tailwind playground? https://play.tailwindcss.com/c7uEH65hsd. Please [edit] your question to include a minimal reproducible example so we can figure out what your problem actually is here.

Isn't a block element having 100% width by default (that would overwrite the min-width)? I tested the min-w-20 class on an element with display: inline-block;and it worked.

@Wongjn I am using the latest version, 3.4.3

@AlexWayne Yes, the class is on the element, but it is not being applied. It is not showing as an element style at all.

I'm also facing the the same issue with min-w-* classes

@AlexWayne I have created an example that is working fine in both ways on tailwind play but in my case the class is on element but didn't take any styles.. it doesn't look like a tailwind class at all.
https://play.tailwindcss.com/KOorrdf2g3

Have you configured tailwind correctly? Is the content path correct? There's not much we can do from here with only the details you've provided, sadly.
